# Человеко-понятные урлы

Tags: apache

Задача такая. Есть урл вида:

```
something1/something2/type1.type2/something
```

Делаю так:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\/\.]*)$ /somewhere.php?url=$1
```

А еще пробовал так:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/\.]*)$ /somewhere.php?url=$1
```

И везде error 500. Сделал так:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\/\.]*)/$ /somewhere.php?url=$1
```

И все заработало, только вот не всегда / в конце урла идет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема решилась :)
Собственно, а чего я мог ожидать, если /somewhere.php совпадает по маске с

```
[a-z0-9/\.]
```

Сам на себя обращался в цикле, вот его и клинило :)

Проблему решил так, написав перед правилом:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```